# AWS Cognito as an Open Id Authorizer for AWS AppSync

Tags: amazon-cognito, openid-connect, aws-appsync

I need to use an AWS Cognito User Pool with the `client_credentials` OAuth Flow on a *different* AWS Account to be an authorization provider for an AWS AppSync App on a *different* AWS Account.

I added the Amazon Cognito Domain (test example below) to the Authorization Providers on AppSync

[image]

I was able to get a valid access token. However, when I used that token to make a request on AppSync I get the following error:

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "errorType": "UnauthorizedException",
            "message": "Valid authorization header not provided."
        }
    ]
}
```

Is it possible to use the Amazon Cognito Domain as the OIDC Issurer URL on AppSync in a different account? Or am I using the wrong domain?

I know this pretty much works out of the box by using the "Amazon Cognito User Pool" authorizer provider but that only works if Cognito and AppSync is on the same account. I also got AuthO OIDC with `client_credentials` to work per this [doc](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/appsync-auth0/) but would like to use cognito on a different account if possible.

Comment: maybe you are accessign resources that are allowed only (for example) with IAM authorization?

Comment: Thanks for the sanity check I did add `@aws_oidc` to my graphql.schema so I believe it should have access to those resources.

Comment: please try `@aws_cognito_user_pools`

Answer (score 4):

The issuer URL should look like this:

`https://cognito-idp.<aws-region>.amazonaws.com/<userpool-id>`

Source:
https://github.com/awslabs/aws-support-tools/tree/master/Cognito/decode-verify-jwt

Comment: Thanks this ended up working! Just for additional context for anyone who gets to this.

The client makes a call to `https://<domain-prefix>.auth.<region>.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/token` for the access_token. The URL that is used to configure AppSync OIDC (mentioned in the thread above) is actually encoded in the token. That URL is what needs to be set on AWS AppSync > App Name > Settings > OpenID Connect provider domain (Issuer URL).